# Change existing JavaScript object functions with prototype?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pagedown

I'm trying to hook PageDown into my Rails app, because the Markdown editor is awesome.

However, I'm finding this difficult because Rails auto-assigns ids via form helpers, and PageDown expects the id "wmd-input" to be assigned to a textarea field.  In my model I have a text property named "body" that I want to serve as the editor, but `f.text_area :body` yields a textarea with the id `post_body`.

So, my current approach is to tell PageDown to associate the editor with a textarea with a particular class name rather than associating it with a particular ID.  This is where I'm confused as to how to proceed.  Here's a [link to Markdown.Editor.js](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Editor.js?r=46bb422ffaa27b3a2895ff3ce8c31f8b491fa9a9).

Navigate to `function PanelCollection(postfix) {` (on line 244).  I want to change the third line in that function from:

```
this.input = doc.getElementById("wmd-input" + postfix);
```

to

```
this.input = doc.getElementsByClassName("wmd-input" + postfix)[0];
```

I've never done anything like this.  Also, editing the source for Markdown.Editor.js isn't really an option since it is auto-generated.  I need to alter the function after it's been created.  How can I do this?

**EDIT #1:**

So, this was my first time forking and contributing back to anything on GitHub, but I forked the pagedown-rails gem and made my change and ensured it worked by connecting the gem listed in my Gemfile to my fork.  Worked beautifully, thanks for the suggestion.  I contributed back [via this pull request](https://github.com/rh/pagedown-rails/pull/2).

Comment: I don't think the question has anything to do with ruby-on-rails or prototypes.

Comment: Why not host the source yourself, and edit that one line yourself? oh, and if it can only be edited at a certain point in time, simply expose the constructor...

Comment: If my reason for making the change is rails-specific, does that not merit an inclusion of the rails tag?

Comment: Nice! +1 for following through while doing it The Right Way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a ***major*** hack, but you could accomplish it by overriding `document.getElementById()` to delegate to `document.getElementsByClassName()` if the passed string starts with `'wmd-input'`:

```
var doc = document;
doc.__getElementByIdOrig = doc.getElementById;
doc.getElementById = function (idStr) {
    if (idStr.match(/^wmd-input/)) {
        var elt = this.getElementsByClassName(idStr)[0];
        return elt ? elt : null;
    }

    return this.__getElementByIdOrig(idStr);
};
```

Comment: I can't think of a cleaner way, honestly.  The PageDown source is part of a gem and I don't like the idea of hacking on gems directly :\

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only option if editing the source is no option.

Comment: Forked and contributed back.  I think the change makes sense for Rails applications.